# Change margin-top on scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

When i scroll, my image has to move `10px` down with `javascript`. i tried a lot, like:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop = "10px";
}
```

css:

```
   #test {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 614px;
      margin-top: 366px;
      width: 32%;
    }
```

but it doesn't worked.

Comment: please give full context of your problem

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: This is my problem, and i dont have any code because i dont no how to do this... I am new to coding

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way how to solve it would be:

- put your html code to div (with id container)
- next you need to do onscroll event (by javascript) -> basically when you scroll the image will move down.

**So the code can look like:**

```
document.getElementById("conatiner").onscroll = function(){
  myScrollDownFunction()
}

function myScrollDownFunction() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop = "376px";
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reaction, but what do you mean by "put your html code to div (with id container)"?

Comment: I mean the content of the page.
<div id="container">
   //your code before the image
</div>

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work... Is there a possibilty that my javascript doest work? Or is there a way i can check if my js is working?

Comment: Yes, you can check if your JS is working - just write this to your javascript file:
alert("Test");
if you get an alert your JS is working if not there is another problem...

Comment: i dont get an alert

Comment: So you dont embled your javascript right.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code on your javascript code.

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display = "inline-block";
```

There is an explanation for display.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Comment: window.onscroll = function() { document.getElementById('test').style.marginTop = "10px"; document.getElementById('test').style.display = "inline-block";}

Comment: Please check the above code and let me know.